# websocketで、数秒ごとに通信を行っているのに30秒ほどで接続がcloseになる

Tags: javascript, nginx, swift4, websocket

websocketを用いたWebアプリを作成しています。
現在、JavaScriptからnew WebSocket("wss://{hostname}")で接続を開始し、onOpenが呼ばれた後は数回、sendメソッドやonmessageイベントハンドラでサーバーとの通信を行えているのですが、無通信状態で無いにもかかわらず、いつも30秒前後でonCloseが発生して接続が切れてしまいます。
※関係あるかわかりませんが、PCの開発環境でlocalhostのAPサーバーとwebsocketを行う場合はこのような問題は起こりません。
接続すらできないとか、無通信状態のときのTimeoutが早い、とかであれば、色々と解決策を見たことがあるのですが、私のような状況の場合、どのような原因が考えられるでしょうか。
（サーバーは、Swift実装のVaporCloudを使っていますが、特定のサーバーによる原因以外でも、何かあれば、教えてください）。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: VaporCloudについては詳しくないのですが、もしかすると実行タイムアウトで強制的にプロセスが殺されているのかもしれません。お使いの環境のスクリプトやプログラムの実行タイムアウトの制限設定がないか、どのような数値が設定されているか確認してみてください。直接的な回答ではありませんが、解決のヒントになれば幸いです。

Comment: localhostだと現象が出ないということは環境の問題である可能性を第一に疑いますね。Vapor Cloudのログを見てなにか出ていないか、３０秒以上のセッションを維持するにはどうしたら良いかサポートに聞いてみると良いかもしれません。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。VaporCloudのログには特にエラーなどは出ていません。また、サポートには以前、サーバー側でタイムアウトの設定が出来るか問い合わせたことがありますが、サーバー側は全体共通の設定としてTimeout設定はしておらず、各アプリごとの個別設定も出来ないとのことでした。※常に通信を行っている状態でも30秒くらいでいきなり切断されるので、Timeout設定の問題ではないかもしれないと思っています。

Answer (score 1):

localhostで発現せず、リモートに接続して毎回30秒前後で接続が切れる場合、ネットワーク構成が気になります。

ひょっとしてAPサーバの前段にロードバランサやプロキシが設置されていて30秒で接続を断つ設定になっていませんか？または手元のルータ、端末のファイヤーウォールに同様の設定があるかもです。

それでもダメならAPサーバが原因だと思いますが、VaporのGithubに類似ケースが投稿されていました。
https://github.com/vapor/vapor/issues/689#issuecomment-293737926

対策としては30秒を超えるタイムアウトを指定すれば良いみたいです。
(2017年の情報ですが）

```
import HTTP
HTTP.defaultServerTimeout = 60 * 60
```